# Styling multiple div toggles differently within one another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have created an toggle of multiple divs to showcase different categories of content. This is one example:

```
<div id="left"> 
<h4 class="expanding-header-active" profile='1'><a href="#">+ 1</a></h4>
 <div class="toggle-container" rel="profile_1">
   <ul>
   <li class="expanding-subhead-active" profile='4'><a href="#">A</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>


<div id="right">
 <div class="toggle-container" rel="profile_4">
<h2>A</h2>
<p>yada yada yada</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I have created a Fiddle that shows more of what I am talking about:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Ymj/1125/)

I need the main divs (+1, +2, +3) to stay open when the inner divs (A, B, C, D, E, and F) are being clicked about.  But, only one of the main divs (+1, +2, +3) can be opened at a time.

The Fiddle is updated to something closer to what I need - but now, is there a way to prevent A and B being opened at the same time without sacrificing the current structure?

Comment: Your fiddle seems completely unrelated to the code you've posted in the question. Could you please add all relevant code in the question.

Comment: Sorry! Wrong Fiddle. It is updated @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Did you write this code?  All you need to do is remove the line `      $(".toggle-container").not($(this).next()).hide(300);` and it will work.

Comment: That keeps them open, but it doesn't close them after a new main div is clicked.  @VtoCorleone

Answer (score 0):

If i think i understand your question correctly, cant you just comment out the line: $(".toggle-container").not($(this).next()).hide(300);

ok, just seen your other comments. I think changing the function like below will achieve what you need.

```
$(".expanding-subhead-active").on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      //$(".toggle-container").not($(this).next()).hide(300);
      $('#right .toggle-container').hide();
      $("div[rel='profile_" + $(this).attr("profile") + "']").show(300,"linear");
```

Comment: I want to be able to click on +1, and be able to go between A & B without +1 closing.  This keeps +1 open when I'm going about +2 and +3, I need these three main divs to be open when the inner letters are being clicked.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to hide this, just remove the command to hide.
Remove this line:

```
$(".toggle-container").not($(this).next()).hide(300);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A8Ymj/1122/

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

Required changing the class of the inside answers to .toggle-container-1 and setting

```
 $('.toggle-container-1').hide();

 $(".expanding-subhead-active").on('click', function(e) {
 $(".toggle-container-1").not($(this).next()).hide(300);
  $("div[rel='profile_" + $(this).attr("profile") + "']").toggle(300, "linear");
});
```

[Correct Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A8Ymj/1128/)

Thanks everyone :) I'm new at this!